# How to draw a line using code comment?

Tags: swift, xcode

[image]

Hi, I want to separate properties and functions using comment.

How to comment in the code to achieve like greenline?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use MARK

Example:

`// MARK: Properties`

Also if you put a dash afterwards it gives you a line separator

```
// MARK: - Properties
```